# 404 page errors on every page except index (hostgator web hosting)

Tags: mod-rewrite, web-hosting

So my friend bought web hosting for his groups website.
I know this question has been asked a million times possibly, but none of the ones asked or answered apply to the same situation I'm in unfortunately.

This is my current .htaccess code

```
# Use PHP56 
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php
```

I know it's something related to enabling mod_rewrite.
If you could explain thoroughly what to do and can help, I'd highly appreciate it. It's been an error on my back for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan here from HostGator support. We were sorry to hear you've had trouble with this issue and would be glad to assist. Nothing is inherently wrong with the code you've provided from the .htaccess file, so there is likely an issue elsewhere. If you could please provide your domain name we'd be glad to investigate with you.

We also have this guide available which might help :

https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/404-error-page

Alternatively, please feel free to start a live chat at https://chat.hostgator.com and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: Nah, I had my own .htaccess code, but it was working perfectly fine when i was running it on xampp or wamp. As soon as I changed the code for hostgator gave me an error "500" and I just refunded.